# Push-through rule for square root of specific projection matrix

Tags: matrix-equations, projection-matrices

Is the following a valid identity?

$$
(I - XX^T)^{1/2} X = X (I - X^T X)^{1/2}
$$

Without the square root, it is quite easy to see that

$$
(I - XX^T) X = X (I - X^T X)
$$

holds but I have trouble verifying that the upper equation holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very general rule exists for these things.

Let $A,B\,$ be any two matrices such that the product $AB$ is a square matrix, and let $f(z)$ be an analytic function of a scalar argument.

Then the following is true
$$f(AB)\cdot A = A\cdot f(BA)$$

The proof consists of a series expansion of the function coupled with the associativity of matrix multiplication.

In this particular case, $\,A=X,\,B=X^T\,$ and  $\,f(z) = \sqrt{1-z}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you have a source for more details on these kinds of theorems?

Comment: I read this theorem in one of [Nick Higham's](https://nhigham.com/) papers; I don't recall which one.

Comment: Thank you, I will look it up!

Answer (score 0):

Making use of the SVD $X = U \Sigma V^T$, one arrives at

$$
(I - X X^T)^{1/2} X = U (I - \Sigma^2)^{1/2} \Sigma V
$$

and

$$
X (I - X^T X)^{1/2} = U \Sigma (I - \Sigma^2)^{1/2} V
$$

where the diagonal entries may be swapped, $\Sigma (I - \Sigma^2)^{1/2} = (I - \Sigma^2)^{1/2} \Sigma$. Hence the identity holds!